# Ajax inside ajax not working

Tags: ajax

I have a function that calls an ajax, inside that ajax another ajax needs to be executed. In the below code I gave my full function. Just to ensure that everything but the 2nd ajax works perfectly, I should point you out that before the 2nd ajax call there is an alert() function which works. That means everything works if I comment the 2nd ajax call. If I uncomment it then after the first alert a second alert should appear saying 'inside 2nd call', but nothing happens. Got any suggestions?

```
function get_employee_list(Parameter){

$.ajax({
    url: 'resource/php/search_profile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { var1 : Parameter},
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        //alert(response);
        reset_search_table();
        $(response).find('employee').each(function() {
            var ebasp_id = $(this).find('ebasp_id').text();
            var ebasp_name = $(this).find('ebasp_name').text();
            var ebasp_gender = $(this).find('ebasp_gender').text();
            var ebasp_category = $(this).find('ebasp_category').text();
            //var ebasp_region_type = $(this).find('ebasp_region_type').text();
            //var ebasp_region_name = $(this).find('ebasp_region_name').text();
            var code_sub_region = $(this).find('ebasp_sub_region').text();
            var code_location = $(this).find('ebasp_location').text();
            var code_office = '';

            if (code_location === '0')
                code_office = code_sub_region;
            else
                code_office = code_location;
            var office = '';

            //alert('before 2nd call -- '+code_office);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'resource/php/show_cost_center_name.php',
                type: POST,
                data: { var1 : code_office},
                success: function(response){
                    office = response;
                    alert('inside 2nd call');
                }
            });

            var ebasp_designation = $(this).find('ebasp_designation').text();
            var ebasp_date_of_joining = $(this).find('ebasp_date_of_joining').text();
            var ebasp_grade = $(this).find('ebasp_grade').text();
            var ebasp_slab = $(this).find('ebasp_slab').text();
            var ebasp_basic = $(this).find('ebasp_basic').text();
            var ebasp_photo_upload = $(this).find('ebasp_photo_upload').text();
            var ebasp_created_on = $(this).find('ebasp_created_on').text();
            var ebasp_created_by = $(this).find('ebasp_created_by').text();

            $("#search_table").show();
            $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+ebasp_id+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_name+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_gender+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_category+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+office+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_designation+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_date_of_joining+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_grade+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_slab+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_basic+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_created_on+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+ebasp_created_by+'</td>').appendTo("#search_table");
        });
    },
    cache: false,
});return false;
}
```

Comment: add error property to your second ajax call and see if second ajax is throwing error

Comment: have you tried handling the error scenario? do you know what was response from the ajax call? have you checked the network tab of debugger to check if the second ajax call was even made?

Comment: 2nd ajax call response = <option>1001002</option>  
  
I don't know how to check 'the network tab of debugger to check if the second ajax call was even made'. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: in chrome : ctrl + Shift + J .... in that click on network tab

Comment: alright I have checked it. 1st call is made but 2nd call isn't. What to do now?

Comment: second ajax call response is <option>1001002</option> ?

Comment: yes. anyways i have found the problem. in 2nd ajax call i didn't use single quote on my POST method, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Great that you found the issue. However please note that you can greatly improve the quality of this code by creating a new function for the second ajax call. Also you are using the variable "office" without waiting for the answer of the second ajax call. Therefore "office" will be empty in that case.

Comment: Thanks! yes I improved it by moving `$('<tr></tr>').html()` inside the success method. But making a different function for 2nd ajax call, that's a bit tough. Because to do that I have to pass the whole function as a parameter. You know making a different function for an ajax call does not work like the typical way. Thanks for your concern anyway.